# Module parse failed: Unexpected token (7:8) File was processed with these loaders When I was using external jsx component in react js

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have an integrated project. It contains some pages (Each page in a folder is a react app). Outside these folder (as a root of them), I want to create some custom components an use them in some of pages.
The structure is as follow:

- node_modules
- AppPage1
- AppPage2
- AppPage3
- SharedComponents
- - MyComponent.jsx
- package.json

Inside each AppPage's package.json, I addressed the MyComponent.jsx in dependencies is:

```
"app-components": "file:./SharedComponents",
```

AppPages can recognize this Components using this:

```
import {MyComponent} from 'app-components/MyComponent'
```

But the following error appears:

> ERROR in ../SharedComponents/MyComponent.jsx 7:8
> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (7:8)
> File was processed with these loaders:

- ../node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
- ../node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.

What should I do to solve this problem?